Showing that a pseudocode algorithm runs in $\Omega(n^3)$
I want to show that this pseudocode algorithm runs in $\Omega(n^3)$.
Input: An n-element array A of numbers, indexed from 1 to n.
Output: The maximum subarray sum of array A
m = 0
for j = 1 to n:
    for k = j to n:
        s = 0
        for i = j to k:
            s = s + A(i)
        if s > m:
            m = s
return m

I wonder how to do this. The book I'm reading says that it is $O(n^3)$. That is because it takes "most n primitive operations" in each of the loops. But what about the Big-Omega?
When I count the number of primitive operations, I get "most" $n^3+3n^2+2$. Surely this is larger than $n^3$, and $\Omega$ is sort of the "lower bound" as I understand it.
The problem I have, is that $n^3+3n^2+2$ is the "most", or "worst case". It will probably be smaller. And then perhaps smaller than $\Omega(n^3)$.
So, what do I do? Do I count the primitive operations "best case"?

Here you have $T(n) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{k=j}^{n} \sum\limits_{i=j}^{k} c$, for some positive constant $c$.
\begin{align*}
T(n) = & \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{k=j}^{n} \sum\limits_{i=j}^{k} c\\
&= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{k=j}^{n} c(k-j+1)\\
&= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \left(c\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-j+1} k\right) \tag{putting $k = k-j+1$}\\
&= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \left(\frac{c}{2} (n-j+1)(n-j+2)\right)\\
&= \frac{c}{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \left( (n-j+1)(n-j+2)\right)\\
&= \frac{c}{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j(j+1) \tag{using symmetry}\\
& = \frac{c}{6} (n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n)
\end{align*}
Thus, of course, you can write this as $\Omega(n^3)$, $O(n^3)$, or $\Theta(n^3)$.

Thanks a lot! Sometimes a bit more mathy stuff can do the trick, as for understanding.

Order notation only cares about the highest degree of $n$ therefore $n^3+3n^2+2$ is $O(n^3)$ and $\Omega(n^3).$
Why is it $\Omega(n^3),$ there is nowhere in the code where you break out of the loops and thus end up with substantially fewer number of primitive operations.
If no replacement of the maximum sum happens, this at most reduces the number of primitive operations by a factor of 2 (counting both the if statement check and the replacement of the max as primitive operations) and does not change the order of operations.
